# Why are my users able to log in despite having is_Active set to false?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am using abstractbaseuser and baseusermanager.

Why are my users able to log in despite having `is_Active` set to `False`?
I thought that `is_active=False` by default makes it such that users cannot login?

If my understanding is wrong, how can I make it default?

**models.py**

```
class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
 def create_user(self, email, username, password=None):
  if not email:
   raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
  if not username:
   raise ValueError('Users must have a username')

  user = self.model(
   email=self.normalize_email(email),
   username=username,
  )

  user.set_password(password)
  user.save(using=self._db)
  return user

 def create_superuser(self, email, username, password):
  user = self.create_user(
   email=self.normalize_email(email),
   password=password,
   username=username,
  )
  user.is_admin = True
  user.is_staff = True
  user.is_superuser = True
  user.save(using=self._db)
  return user

class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
 email                  = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
 username               = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
 is_admin               = models.BooleanField(default=False)
 is_active              = models.BooleanField(default=True)
 is_staff               = models.BooleanField(default=False)
 is_superuser           = models.BooleanField(default=False)

 objects = MyAccountManager()

 def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
  return self.is_admin

 def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
  return True
```

**settings.py**

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'account.Account'
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ( 
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.AllowAllUsersModelBackend', 
    'account.backends.CaseInsensitiveModelBackend',
    )
```

Comment: Are you using a Custom Authentication Backend? Also you default for is_active is True here...

Comment: Where exactly you do set it to false, as default in your model is True. Did you check the database

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. But basically I made a deactivate users view such that when they deactivate their account, their is_active will be set to false. I double checked my admin and yep it really went to is_active= False

Comment: however, when I tried to login with the deactivated account, i was able to log in

Comment: btw hi its u again and youre super active haha

Comment: Hi I'm using these 2 authentication backends: `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'account.Account'
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ( 
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.AllowAllUsersModelBackend', 
    'account.backends.CaseInsensitiveModelBackend',
    )
`

Comment: so did you check what AllowAllUsersModelBackend does ?https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.backends.AllowAllUsersModelBackend

Comment: oh thanks man!!! @iklinac what other backends can be used to replace this just to solve the is_active problem without affecting other codes?

Comment: is it simply replacing the above with `ModelBackend`

Answer (score -1):

The django documentation mentioned

> is_active
> instead of deleting accounts; that way, if your applications have any
> foreign keys to users, the foreign keys won’t break.
>
> This doesn’t necessarily control whether or not the user can log in.
> Authentication backends aren’t required to check for the is_active
> flag but the default backend (ModelBackend) and the RemoteUserBackend
> do. You can use AllowAllUsersModelBackend or
> AllowAllUsersRemoteUserBackend if you want to allow inactive users to
> login. In this case, you’ll also want to customize the
> AuthenticationForm used by the LoginView as it rejects inactive users.
> Be aware that the permission-checking methods such as has_perm() and
> the authentication in the Django admin all return False for inactive
> users.
>
> Blockquote> Boolean. Designates whether this user account should be considered
> active. We recommend that you set this flag to False

Comment: Please try to help author instead of just copy/paste the documentation

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).